# No instance for (Integral [t0]) error in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I'm getting an error:

`No instance for (Integral [t0])` when I run this haskell code.

```
boomBangs xs = [(a,b,c) |a<-[1..xs],b<-[1..xs],c<-[1..xs], xs <- xs `div` 2]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to divide a list. In particular, `` xs `div` 2 `` is the incorrect expression.

You can get this from the error message: it's complaining that `[t0]` does not behave like an integer (e.g. it isn't in the `Integral` class). `[t0]` is just a list of stuff--the `t0`, being in lowercase, is a type variable that represntes *any* type.

Since lists of stuff aren't numbers, we can't really know how to divide them.

You can see why you get this exact error message by looking at the type of `div`:

```
div :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
```

All this means is that given some type `i` in the `Integral` class, you can divide two of them together to get a third. Since lists of things are not part of the integral class, you can't divide them and so you get an error.

If `div` had a concrete type like `div :: Int -> Int -> Int`, you would get an error telling you that it can't match the expected type `Int` with the actual type `[t0]`. However, since the type actually contains a variable `i`, the error is a bit more complex: `[t0]` cannot be a valid type to use in place of `i` because it is not in the `Integral` class.

Answer (score 6):

What you said was:

> Give me a tuple of `a`, `b`, and `c`:
>
> ```
> [ (a, b, c)
> ```
>
> For each `a`, `b`, and `c` in the list of values from `1` to `xs1`:
>
> ```
> | a <- [1..xs1]
> , b <- [1..xs1]
> , c <- [1..xs1]
> ```
>
> For each `xs2` in the quotient of `xs1` and 2.
>
> ```
> , xs2 <- xs1 `div` 2
> ]
> ```

If you compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) or turn them on in GHCi (`:set -Wall`) then you’ll get a warning that the `xs` in `xs <- ...` shadows the `xs` in `boomBangs xs = ...`, and also that it’s unused. Obviously this kind of warning can be very helpful, as it points right to your problem.

Since `xs1` is the input to your function, you end up with a type like this:

```
(Integral [t]) => [t] -> [([t], [t], [t])]
```

Which is to say that the function takes a list (`xs1`) that can act as a number (`` (`div` 2) ``) and gives you back a list of tuples of such lists. Even though you’re trying to divide a list by a number, GHC allows it and infers a more general type because you *could* have defined an `Integral` instance for lists. It only discovers that you haven’t when you actually try to *use* the function on a concrete type. Writing down type signatures can help keep the compiler grounded and give you better error messages.

I can only guess you meant for `boomBangs` to have a type like:

```
Integral t => [t] -> [(t, t, t)]
```

Or just:

```
[Int] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

In which case maybe you were thinking of something like this:

```
[ (a, b, c)
| x <- xs
, a <- [1..x `div` 2]
, b <- [1..x `div` 2]
, c <- [1..x `div` 2]
]
```